# First film to feature a real news reader playing themselves reading the news?

Tags: first-appearance

Does anyone know the first film to use a real news reader or TV presenter playing 'themselves' and reading the news? eg Larry King in *Ghostbusters*.

Comment: @closevoters ID questions might be off-topic, but this isn't one. [Tag:first-appearance] questions are on-topic here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A good candidate for the first person to do this is [H.V. Kaltenborn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H._V._Kaltenborn) in [Mr. Smith Goes to Washington](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Smith_Goes_to_Washington) (1939). From [Wikiquote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Mr._Smith_Goes_to_Washington):

> H.V. Kaltenborn: [Announcing on the radio] Half of official Washington is here to see democracy's finest show, the filibuster, the right to talk your head off, the American privilege of free speech in its most dramatic form. The least man in that chamber, once he gets and holds that floor by the rules, can hold it and talk as long as he can stand on his feet providing always, first, that he does not sit down, second, that he does not leave the chamber or stop talking. The galleries are packed. In the diplomatic gallery are the envoys of two dictator powers. They have come here to see what they can't see at home. DEMOCRACY IN ACTION.

[image: Image of Kaltenborn on the radio from Mr. Smith Goes to Washington]

Comment: nice one. My partner is into her old film but we don't seem to have this one. Have you seen it yourself?